# AutocompleteTextView with custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter to set the adapter on an AutocompleteTextView (AddressAdapter extends ArrayAdapter).

Because I'm using the dropdown list to show the addresses and the distance to the actual position, I have to parametrize the Array Adapter with Address.

The problem comes here: the method

`public Address getItem(int position)`

gives the selected item of the Addresses list. Due to I'm using Address as the Adapter base class when I click on one of the suggestions the TextBox is filled with the toString() representation of Address class.

How can I change this default behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `getView()` method to change the default view of each item.

You can extract the `TextView` and since `getView()` also passes you the position, you can use that to retrieve the data object and manipulate the values that you are displayed.